# Remove files for a lot of directories - Linux

Tags: linux, file, rm

How can I remove all `.txt` files present in several directories

```
Dir1 >
  Dir11/123.txt
  Dir12/456.txt
  Dir13/test.txt
  Dir14/manifest.txt
```

In my example I want to run the remove command from `Dir1`.

I know the linux command `rm`, but i don't know how can I make this works to my case.

PS.: I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're not going to enter sub directories so no need to use find; everything is at the same level. I think this is what you're looking for: `rm */*.txt`

Before you run this you can try `echo */*.txt` to see if the correct files are going to be removed.

Using find would be useful if you want to search subfolders of subfolders, etc.

There is no Dir1 in the current folder so don't do `find Dir1 ...`. If you run the find from the prompt above this will work:

`find . -type f -name "*.txt" -delete`

Answer (score 3):

To do what you want recursively, `find` is the most used tool in this case. Combined with the `-delete` switch, you can do it with a single command (no need to use `-exec` (and forks) in `find` like other answers in this thread) :

```
find Dir1 -type f -name "*.txt" -delete
```

if you use [bash4](/questions/tagged/bash4), you can do too :

```
( shopt -s globstar; rm Dir1/**/*.txt )
```

Comment: Added `bash` solution and some explanations